# Regex for phone number validation with min and max length check

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a simple javascript regex to validate phone numbers.
Only digits, "+" at the beginning and "-" 
Max and min length of digits should be 10 - 12

The next phones should be allowed: 
1. +380631505624  
2. 0631505624  
3. 063-15-05-624

The next phones should be NOT allowed: 
1. +38063+1505624  
2. asd0631505624  
3. -063-15-05-624-  
4. +0---3-1--24

Comment: Don't try to mandate formatting. **strip** formatting characters (spaces, parentheses, dashes, etc) before testing phone numbers.

Comment: good idea. Do you mean to get only digits and validate length ?

Comment: @OlegDats: Keep the digit and the `+` (AFAIK, the `+` is important). The rest can be removed.

Comment: could the "-" characters be in exactly the same places in phone number or the number can be like "+38063-11-11-11-1"?

Comment: +1 to @Quentin's comment. You really want to strip any spaces and/or formatting before it gets to the regex. Also: *exactly* 10 or 12 digits? or is 11 digits valid?

Comment: @nhahtdh it looks like in DB it should be String "+{numbers}" but not as a Number

Comment: You could check this code. http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: are all phone's country codes have 3 digits and starts with "+" ?

Comment: @OlegDats — No. USA: `+1` (one digit). UK: `+44` (two digits). And the `+` is just a convention meaning "Country code follows". In the UK you would dial `001` to get to the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Comment of Quentin is the way to go**, but a Regex - Expression  for your needs could be:

```
^\+?\d+(\d\-|\d)+\d$
```

I hope it helps, or is atleast a point in the right direction

It all depends on how save/strict you want to check

BTW.: is javascript ist would look something like this

```
 ...
 if (/^\+?(\d\-|\d)+\d$/ig.test("+43595-995-995")){
    alert("GOOD");
 }
 ...
```

Here you can find a working demo( [On JsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/KRwHQ/) ) tested wit Chrome 24+
(with all numbers of your question)

Comment: it could be optimized, shorted, spezialized,... depends on you exact needs.

Comment: works great, thanks man.
FYI: I have decided to strip formatting characters (spaces, parentheses, dashes, etc) and validate only by length.

Answer (score 0):

In above code there has no any lenght validation, so I am just correcting the above answer

http://jsfiddle.net/KRwHQ/4/

```
 if (/^\+?((\d\-|\d)+\d){4,}$/ig.test("+43595-995-995")){
     alert("GOOD");
 }
```